# Git removing newlines?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to learn how to get a previous version of a single file (not all files in a commit).

I was using the method described [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/14855/how-to-checkout-a-single-file-from-git) by right clicking the file, then Log Selected, selecting the commit with the version of my file I want, then right clicking and selecting Reset to Commit.

It's all well and good except for one thing... The version I have back has all newlines stripped. For Example:

Original file

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

Now say I made some changes to this file, as well as some others and I only want to undo changes made to this file, and no others.

File after "Reset to Commit"

```
Line 1Line 2Line 3Line 4
```

At this point the preview of the file is out of sync with what the actual file is. I can fix my file and recommit it (which I shouldn't have to do anyway) but then the previewer shows extra blank lines that my file doesn't actually have.

Is there something I'm doing wrong when trying to check out an older version of a single file?

Comment: That would be a feature of git and not really related to SourceTree.  I don't think there is any way to change this setting through the SourceTree gui, but you can read about the different options here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Comment: They may not be stripped but rather converted to a different kind of line end. I mention this because I've had trouble cooperating with Windows users who mess up my files with their line endings (I use Unix line endings).

Comment: @matt, I'm fairly certain you are right. Until I've sorted this out, I've just made note to not attempt this.

Comment: One problem is that it can be hard to see the line endings. :) Use BBEdit or TextWrangler to see easily what kind of line endings a file has and to change the type. That's what I do when someone has messed up line endings. Of course this all means an extra commit but that's not terribly important.